# Gatsby - fetching remote images with createRemoteFileNode

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I've been trying to fetch images from remote URL to Gatsby Source File system, to take advantage of lazy loading with `gatsby-image` plugin. I have a restful API which returns json with a string containing the image url. I followed [this guide](https://www.wildsmithstudio.com/blog/remote-images-with-gatsby/) as I'm quite new to Gatsby Node Api and wasn't sure how to tackle this. Everything worked well until the point with adding additional properties to image with `createNodeField`. The properties seem to be added (I can see the object with `fields` property when I log the fileNode to the console. However, when trying to query the images, I get an error:

[image]

I'm wondering if there's something wrong in my code or is it due to the changes in gatsby? I'm using gatsby version `2.0.2`. Is there a better option to somehow add additional properties to the image in order to be able to query just the needed ones?

Here's how my `gatsby.node.js` looks like:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const { createRemoteFileNode } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);
    
exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions, createNodeId, node, store, cache } => {
  const { createNode, createNodeField } = actions;
  const processProject = project => {
    project.photos.forEach(async photo => {
      let fileNode;

      try {
        fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
          url: photo.photo.url,
          store,
          cache,
          createNode,
          createNodeId: id => `projectPhoto-${photo.id}`,
        });

        await createNodeField({
          node: fileNode,
          name: 'ProjectPhoto',
          value: 'true',
        });

        await createNodeField({
          node: fileNode,
          name: 'created_at',
          value: photo.created_at,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn('error creating node', error);
      }
    });
  }
  
  return axios.get(baseApiUrl).then(res => {
    res.data.forEach(project => {
      const nodeData = processProject(project);
      createNode(nodeData);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Gatsby fetches assets whence you run the dev/build commands so, I'd say try and loose the async pattern. It's not really giving you anything here and it might be mixing the execution times such that the Node APIs are firing out of sequence.

Comment: You mean to just use `.then` to consume the Promise instead of async/await? I don't think it should be an issue. The example in [gatsby-source-filesystem plugin docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-filesystem/?=#example-usage-1) uses async/await too.

Comment: Just an idea. Out of order execution stuff seems to happen a lot with Gatsby builds on my end. The other thing that kinda jumps out at me is that maybe you don't need to be using the node API to do this. I only use `createPage` to pass the minimum data into Node to dynamically create the page. On the page itself, I do image queries via GraphQL. Does this make sense? Check out this question I made couple weeks back, similar problem I had with Contentful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360940/graphql-query-callbacks-for-gatsby-js

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought of using just `createPage`. That actually makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately I also wanted to add an index page with listings of all the projects (I don't generate that page dynamically, but I guess I could do that as well). Somehow I managed to get everything working by restructuring everything a bit. I've used `onCreateNode` (apart from images I create other data) and just declared the parent/children relationship there. Also it seems like using forEach didn't play nice with async/await. I used for of loop and somehow this works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end it seems that using `.forEach` with async/await was messing stuff up for some reason. Doing everything in for of loop, fixed the problem, although eslint was complaining about that a lot. Here's the code:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const { createRemoteFileNode } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);

exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions, createNodeId, node, store, cache } => {
  const { createNode, createNodeField } = actions;
  const processProject = project => {
    for (const photo of project.photos) {
      let fileNode;

      try {
        fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
          url: photo.photo.url,
          store,
          cache,
          createNode,
          createNodeId: id => `projectPhoto-${photo.id}`,
        });

        await createNodeField({
          node: fileNode,
          name: 'ProjectPhoto',
          value: 'true',
        });

        await createNodeField({
          node: fileNode,
          name: 'created_at',
          value: photo.created_at,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn('error creating node', error);
      }
    }
  }

  return axios.get(baseApiUrl).then(res => {
    res.data.forEach(project => {
       const nodeData = processProject(project);
       createNode(nodeData);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, just curious - what was the end goal of this code? What exactly gets created, a big page of images?

Comment: I have an api which gives me back json with array of objects (each object is a project with some details + urls for images). I wanted to display all the images for a given project along with the project details. At the end I modified solutions from what's here. I created Project Node, then added ProjectPhoto Nodes and created parent/child link between them. The idea was to 1) get data from the api 2) grab those image from urls using `createRemoteFileNode`, so they could be lazy loaded 3) create connection between those 2 nodes to be able to pull correct images for the project.

Comment: It was my first time playing with Gatsby Node API, so probably I overcomplicated things a bit and I'm not 100% sure if that would be the best approach for this.

Comment: How would you query this ?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor
`export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($id: String!) {
    ProjectImages: project(id: { eq: $id }) {
      childrenFile {
        id
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 720, quality: 85) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;`

You can check [this repo](https://github.com/janczizikow/janczizikow-portfolio) for more context.